# Grunt-Built Production env, angularJS nomod error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, gruntjs

I built an angularJS app scaffolded by yeoman, and the test environment with

```
grunt serve
```

went just as I expected, but when I tried to build the production environment with

```
grunt build
```

and run it with a nodemon, and I got no content except for the header/footer, and my chrome javascript console gave me the following error.

```
 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.12/$injector/nomod?p0=myApp
    at http://localhost:3000/scripts/vendor.c0d4f7d6.js:3:20442
    at http://localhost:3000/scripts/vendor.c0d4f7d6.js:3:28774
    at b (http://localhost:3000/scripts/vendor.c0d4f7d6.js:3:28346)
    at b (http://localhost:3000/scripts/vendor.c0d4f7d6.js:3:28658)
    at http://localhost:3000/scripts/vendor.c0d4f7d6.js:4:5159
    at f (http://localhost:3000/scripts/vendor.c0d4f7d6.js:3:20827)
    at n (http://localhost:3000/scripts/vendor.c0d4f7d6.js:4:4937)
    at Sb (http://localhost:3000/scripts/vendor.c0d4f7d6.js:4:6627)
    at h (http://localhost:3000/scripts/vendor.c0d4f7d6.js:3:26459)
    at _ (http://localhost:3000/scripts/vendor.c0d4f7d6.js:3:26769)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.12/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=E…0(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fscripts%2Fvendor.c0d4f7d6.js%3A3%3A26769)vendor.c0d4f7d6.js:3 (anonymous function)vendor.c0d4f7d6.js:4 (anonymous function)vendor.c0d4f7d6.js:3 fvendor.c0d4f7d6.js:4 nvendor.c0d4f7d6.js:4 Sbvendor.c0d4f7d6.js:3 hvendor.c0d4f7d6.js:3 _vendor.c0d4f7d6.js:3 $vendor.c0d4f7d6.js:7 (anonymous function)vendor.c0d4f7d6.js:2 _.Callbacks.kvendor.c0d4f7d6.js:2 _.Callbacks.l.fireWithvendor.c0d4f7d6.js:2 _.extend.readyvendor.c0d4f7d6.js:1 g
```

http://start.jcolemorrison.com/building-an-angular-and-express-app-part-1/

I was basically following this, and when i did npm start i got basically a blank page. Any suggestions?

Comment: Your myApp module is not loaded that's why you are getting this error. Can you confirm that your javascript files are loaded properly?

Comment: how you define your module `myApp` ?

Comment: @Rebornix I did "yo angular [app name here]" and it auto scaffolded, and right after that when  I tried to grunt build and then run express, it got me this error.

Comment: just show me app.js then I can have an idea how your app is defined.